# Is this a good solution for Card holder applications?

Tags: java, architecture, javascript, microservices

### Business case

I am currently looking for a better architecture to replace the current implementation for my application.

Currently, My application runs on a mainframe system with CICS used for connecting the services and publishing it on the internet. The application deals with very sensitive data and can not compromise even a minute of downtime as it lies under Card holder domain. For FE, I use java technologies. Assuming my application contains a startpage(just like any other web app) with lots of menus connecting to different screens. And the FE application is deployed on Websphere app server.

### My Idea

I am thinking of making each menu functionality as a microservice and the startpage as other microservice app using Angular 2(maybe serverless?). Whenever any menu item is clicked it will invoke the microservice and should display the screen. Here I have 2 questions.

1. Should my microservice contain all the UI code and logical processing in its own microservice?
2. Or All the UI part should be written along with the startpage, and microservice should be called only for logic processing?
3. What would be best to replace my current websphere application server? Can it be serverless?

As an answer, I would expect answerer's to suggest me any alternate or better way to do this? Any other architecture that would be suited? Any other technology stack which will be best suited for this scenario? I am looking it to be cloud oriented. Also, an important concern here is If i host something on cloud architecture, it has to be PCI compliant.

I have asked the same question on SO as well, but didnt recieve any response.

Your answer is most appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please delete your SO question quickly if you don't want a mod to throw a dice which of the two they will delete, you obviously missed the strict "no crossposts" policy of the SE network. And saying you got no reponse in **two hours** is pretty ridiculous, be a little bit more patient and give it at least 3 days. You are asking about a technology stack wich I don't expect many of the experts here knowing well.

Comment: I deleted that one, I didn't knew it was against the policy, thanks for letting me know. Any other way I can do to get response quickly? Because I know its my problem, but I have only a days time to decide on this.

Comment: The SE sites offer free service, completely driven by volunteers who like to answer people's question in their spare time - so you can be lucky to get a good answer shortly, or unlucky and get never one. If you want support in time, you need to hire a consultant.